# MDX - Storybook + React + Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, babeljs, storybook

I try to use MDX markup in building live docs for my storybook. When I run the storybook I get this error:

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):

```
SyntaxError: C:/Users/User/Desktop/priority-style-react/src/stories/Button1.stories.mdx: Unexpected token (12:9)

  10 | const makeShortcode = name => function MDXDefaultShortcode(props) {
  11 |   console.warn("Component " + name + " was not imported, exported, or provided by MDXProvider as global scope")
> 12 |   return <div {...props}/>
     |          ^
  13 | };
  14 | const Preview = makeShortcode("Preview");
  15 | const layoutProps = {
```

my webpack config to load `.mdx` is:

```
config.module.rules.push({
    test: /\.mdx?$/,
    use: [{loader: "babel-loader"}, {loader: '@mdx-js/loader'}],
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    include: [/src/]
});
```

storybook config.js:

```
import { configure, addDecorator } from '@storybook/react';
import { withKnobs } from '@storybook/addon-knobs';

import '../style/index.scss';

const req = require.context('../src/stories', true, /.stories.(tsx|mdx)/);

addDecorator(withKnobs);
configure(req, module);
```

looks like loader works incorrectly.
Can anyone help me to understand what I missed?

Comment: Can someone help with the error similar this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76914413/storybook-cannot-read-properties-of-null-reading-referencemeta-error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, guys, maybe this answer will be helpful for someone and save a lot of precious time.

I fixed this issue just with deleting configuration for `.mdx` extension in `webpack.config.js`. I just left my storybook config.js as it is. And the issue disappeared.

Also, you will faced this issue if you have blank lines between the JSX code in your .mdx file, as Zunaib Imtiaz answered.

Good luck, guys!

Answer (score 3):

Okay there is something very silly in MDX files

It does not accept blank lines as we speak.

```
const makeShortcode = name => function MDXDefaultShortcode(props) {
console.warn("Component " + name + " was not imported, exported, or provided by MDXProvider as global scope")
return <div {...props}/>
 // remove this blank line here.
};
```

to

```
const makeShortcode = name => function MDXDefaultShortcode(props) {
console.warn("Component " + name + " was not imported, exported, or provided by MDXProvider as global scope")
return <div {...props}/>
};
```

And it should work as i scratched my head around this for hours.

Comment: Thank you, for your answer. I faced such an issue too. But in this case, It was an error of double configuration (in the storybook config and webpack config).

Comment: can you kindly share your findings @Ihor Lavs