# Storybook Cannot read properties of null (reading 'referenceMeta') error

Tags: reactjs, mdx, storybook

I am quite new in React and trying to build a documentation page with Storybook. I am trying the ButtonDocs example located in the: https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/writing-docs/doc-blocks. But it gives the error

```
Cannot read properties of null (reading 'referenceMeta')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'referenceMeta')
```

What issue can cause it?

ButtonDocs.mdx file:

```
{/* ButtonDocs.mdx */}

import { Meta, Primary, Controls, Story } from '@storybook/blocks';
import * as ButtonStories from '../../stories/Button.stories';

<Meta of={ButtonStories} />

# Button

A button is ...

<Primary />

## Props

<Controls />

## Stories

### Primary

A button can be of primary importance.

<Story of={ButtonStories.Primary} />

A button can be of secondary importance.

<Story of={ButtonStories.Secondary} />
```

Introduction.jsx:

```
import React from "react";
import Navbar from "../../components/navbar/Navbar";
import Sidebar from "../../components/sidebar/Sidebar";
import "./introduction.scss";
import { MDXProvider } from "@mdx-js/react";
import Content from './ButtonDocs.mdx';


const components = {
  em: props => <i {...props} />
}



const Introduction = () => {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <Sidebar />

      <div className="introduction">
        <Navbar />
        <div className="content">
          <MDXProvider components={components}>
            <Content />
          </MDXProvider>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Introduction;
```